# Windows 8 App Hub Tiles

Tags: windows-8, live-tile

Is there a way in which I can create custom live tiles inside a Windows 8 app but which does not require the purchasing of any kits such as telerik, syncfusion etc... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Callisto Toolkit](http://callistotoolkit.com/) has live tile.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript there is a free jQuery plugin called [metro-js](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs). Also [metro-css](http://metroui.org.ua/tiles.php) has a nice CSS implementation for tiles.

For XAML I only know a [example for Windows Phone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-XAML-Create-3707b497). Because of the same api you maybe can adopt most of the concept to a Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an template that uses hubtile from wp7 on windows 8. it works perfectly 
[Template](https://github.com/hmadrigal/CodeSamples/tree/master/HubTileSampleApp)

i  developed an app with this template and it pass the certification.

Comment: I am using just one page with a grid and each grid item directs the user to a separate page. Can I still apply this or is it just for a grid app? Also is there some simplified version of this as I am not sure how to apply it to my project

Answer (score 0):

How to implement the HUbtile effect(windows 8) using only CSS3 and HTML5 and JS in .net project